# How to use MimeMessageHelper to send email with attachment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mime-types, mime

I am unable to correctly send email with attachment. I am using Gradle and Spring 5. Everything is setup correctly as I was already sending emails with text and html. After a while text requirements I was sending to customers surpassed limitations of email, so I need to extract plain text to CSV file and send it in email as an attachment.
It looks like I am getting only a part of the file attached, but not the complete file?

Code:

```
for(Entry<String, List<LabDipRequest>> entry : userNotificationMap.entrySet())
    {                           
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
            messageHelper.setFrom(fromEmail);
            messageHelper.setTo(entry.getKey());
            messageHelper.setSubject("Exception Report");
            String val = ldReport.generateLabDipExceptionReport(entry.getValue());
            messageHelper.setText(val);
            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("ExceptionReport.csv"));
            messageHelper.addAttachment("ExceptionReport.csv", file);
        });
    }
```

The email body won't send correctly.
This is what I get as the original message in the email inbox:

> Subject: Report
>  MIME-Version: 1.0
>  Content-Type:
> multipart/mixed; 
> boundary="----=_Part_0_927559004.1603720386263"

There is also a log I am outputting if it provides any additional clarification:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com <hidden> - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 25
EHLO mongo.<hidden>.com
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [<hidden>]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO mongo.<hidden>.com
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [<hidden>]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN <hidden>
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "<hidden>"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=dummyaccount@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: <hidden>
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<dummyaccount@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK <hidden>.33 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<dummyaccount@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK <hidden>.33 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   dummyaccount@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead <hidden>.33 - gsmtp
Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 10:38:17 -0400 (EDT)
From: dummyaccount@gmail.com
To: dummyaccount@gmail.com
Message-ID: <<hidden>@mongo.<hidden>.com>
Subject: Report
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_190448734.1603723096935"

.
250 2.0.0 OK  1603723099 <hidden>.33 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection <hidden>.33 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Don't set things on the `message` set them through the helper you have constructed. Also use a proper name (with extension) for the filename.

Comment: If you set the text on the message you are sending a plain text message and losing the attachments because that isn't multipart. When using the helper it stays multipart and will send the message accordingly. I have no idea what you added as it is totally unreadable (don't add additional information as comments but as proper code blocks in your question). As I also mentioned you should set a proper filename with an extension, without that it won't properly detect the type for the multipart to use.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am sorry, understand I should update the question and correct file extension, but the issue remains. I updated my question and added the result of what I get as an email after I updated the file extension and used helper.

Comment: Is the file readable, as there should be 2 parts in your message, apparently there is only 1. Try adding the `File` as an attachment instead of the `FileSystemResource`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes. I added checking, if File is readable add it as an attachment, and the file is readable and successfully added as attachment. At this point I tried every alternative, but still getting the same email over and over, without a clue why the attachment is not in the email. I updated the code above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure that the problem is in the wrong file path. Use only `FileSystemResource` with mime messages. Try this code:

```
@SneakyThrows
@Async
public void sendEmailWithAttachment(String pathToAttachment) {
    MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();

    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

    helper.setSubject(yourSubject);
    helper.setText(yourContent);
    helper.setTo(yourTo);
    helper.setFrom(yourFrom);

    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File(pathToAttachment));
    helper.addAttachment("LabDip", file);

    emailSender.send(message);
}
```

Comment: The issue remains. Tried with FileSystemResource, File only, StreamInput... No matter how I read the file, the email body is always PART_0 etc.